# Unable to upgrade corda 3.3 to corda 4.0

Tags: corda

I am unable to upgrade corda 3.3 to corda 4.0

I have followed the steps given in corda official documentation for upgrading corda 3.3 to corda 4.0

ext.corda_release_version = '4.0'

Corda build successful should come but instead it showing build failure missing jars

Comment: Can you provide error stacktrace?

Comment: Can you provide error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to check out the build.gradle files in the V4.0 CorDapp template.

You'll need to bump up the other plugins e.g.

```
ext {
        corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
        corda_release_version = '4.0'
        corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.42'
        kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
        junit_version = '4.12'
        quasar_version = '0.7.10'
        slf4j_version = '1.7.25'
        log4j_version = '2.11.2'
        corda_platform_version = '4'
    }
```

Comment: I have done this in the first but problem is not with this.. The problem is with cordapp{ } arguments...!!

Comment: Could you let us know what your `build.gradle` file looks like and what errors you are getting?